# Finding Last Fired time using a Cron Expression in Python

Tags: python, cron

I want to know what's the last time instance is given a cron job?

Ex:

Cron expression @hourly

If I run the code at Oct 23 2:30 pm (datetime.now()), it should return Oct 22 2:00 pm.

I know Java has a package but any implementation in Python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime


base = datetime(2020,11,21,00,13)
print(base)
expression = "30 * * * *"

itr = croniter(expression,base)
print(itr.get_next(datetime))
print(itr.get_prev(datetime))
print(itr.get_prev(datetime))
```

1. [croniter on GitHub](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter)
2. [croniter on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/croniter)

Answer (score 1):

Found the package at last!

Croniter

https://pypi.org/project/croniter/